# Do all primes occur as a factor of $p_{k}-2$ for some k?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Can we prove that for any prime p, sufficiently large n, and $$A_n=\prod_{k=2}^n (p_k-2)$$ that $p|A_n$? I checked through $p=p_{50}.$

Comment: It is not true for $p=2$. You can restate this much more simply: If $p$ is and odd prime, is there always a prime $q$ such that $p\mid q-2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: given an odd prime $p$, there is a prime $q$ of the form $2+kp$.

In fact, there are infinitely many primes of that form.
That's a direct consequence of [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: Perhaps someone else knows a proof that does not depend on Dirichlet's theorem.